# IP reservation on Belkin N300 router

Tags: wireless-router, printer

I've been looking for it for months but I cannot find it. I have a belkin N300 router where all pc's are connected to. There is also 1 network-Printer connected (HP Photosmart B110a).

The problem with this printer is that the printer changes his IP-address frequently (almost every time it restarts) which results in a whole reconfiguration of every pc in the network.

Normally the driver software does this by himself, but fails to do it every 2-3 months. Can someone help me to find the IP-reservation setting on my router?

Comment: You have many options. If your router supports it, you may be able to assign an IP address based on MAC address - check the DHCP section. If not, you could increase the lease time of the IP address to reduce the frequency of the changes. Alternatively you may be able to turn off DHCP on the printer and set a static IP address manually. Lastly, you may be able to install DD-WRT on your router which definitely supports IP reservation.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the DHCP client page?

Comment: Hello the only thing i can see on my dhcp-section is a list of the clients. I also have some dhcp-settings on my lan-settings section.
http://i.imgur.com/0c1ep9V.jpg http://i.imgur.com/Y2dkYrE.jpg

Comment: I would try to disable DHCP on the printer and set an IP address manually (outside the DHCP pool). Your router does not appear to support IP reservation as it is a fairly low-end model. Also it is not compatible with DD-WRT after all.

Comment: DHCP on Belkin wireless routers is limited to only supplying dynamic addresses at all which means you have to trust the DHCP server ALWAYS serves the same address. To complicate matters, some of these routers will not serve a manually assigned address. I had to switch off the router's dhcp and run my own on a network computer. Very dissapointing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As James said in the comments on my question. I had to disable DHCP on the printer and assign a static IP-address to it.